# GCC in error when compiling R package on Cloudera CDH4

Tags: r, gcc, hadoop, cloudera, rcpp

I am trying to install RHadoop on Cloudera's CDH4 Hadoop VM.  RHadoop is a framework for using Hadoop via an R programming interface.  One of the prerequisites to installing the RHadoop R package "rmr" is another R package called Rcpp, which is for calling C++ code from R.  When I attempt to install the package, I get the following error.  I contacted both the Rcpp and RHadoop communities and both say its a GCC problem.  When I try to update or reinstall GCC, I get
"Package gcc-4.4.6-4.e16.x86_64 already installed and latest version, nothing to do."  Any suggestions?

Here is the error (from the R command line).

```
> install.packages("Rcpp")
Installing package(s) into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
 trying URL 'http://cran.csdb.cn/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.9.15.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2119769 bytes (2.0 Mb)
opened URL
 ==============================
====================
downloaded 2.0 Mb

* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
 g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c DateVector.cpp -o DateVector.o
 g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Datetime.cpp -o Datetime.o
 g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c DatetimeVector.cpp -o DatetimeVector.o
 g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Dimension.cpp -o Dimension.o
 g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c DottedPair.cpp -o DottedPair.o
 g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Environment.cpp -o Environment.o
 g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Evaluator.cpp -o Evaluator.o
 g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Formula.cpp -o Formula.o
 g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Function.cpp -o Function.o
 g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Language.cpp -o Language.o
 g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Module.cpp -o Module.o
 {standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:10671: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
{standard input}:11544: Error: bad register name `%'
{standard input}:11544: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
 g++: Internal error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
make: *** [Module.o] Error 1
 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpGdXO9h/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
 Making packages.html  ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rcpp") :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 4):

As one of the Rcpp authors, I can assure that the error is probably at your end and with either gcc (unlikely) or CDH.  Rcpp gets built and rebuild a bazillion times both on CRAN (and yes there are [pages summarizing the builds on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_Rcpp.html) and [also on Debian](https://buildd.debian.org/status/package.php?p=rcpp).  The package does not normally kill the compiler.

Could you be running out of ram on the box?

Comment: That was a good guess.  I increased the amount of RAM and that seemed to fix it.  Thanks so much!

Comment: In that case please consider accepting and possibly also upvoting the answer -- by clicking  the on the 'up-arrow' and 'tickmark', respectively.

Comment: I've seen the same issue happening sort of randomly when compiling a package that depends on Rcpp on a virtual machine with I guess not enough ram.